# I need to show logged user's name

Tags: php, passwords, protector

I am using this webpage password protector

It's working fine but i want to make the logged user's name appears in the protected page after logging in successfully.
May you please help me ?

Comment: `<?php if(condition){ echo $username; } ?>`

Comment: may you please explaine ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: You'll need to post **your** code; this is guesswork. Echo the variable assigned to the username in a conditional statement if it meets the condition(s).

Comment: i already posted the link of used code

Comment: I'm not going to download anything, sorry. The rules on Stack are: "Post your code".

Comment: ah ok .. sorry .. i will put it here

Comment: Replace any credentials with `xxx` such as passwords etc.

Comment: please visit now .. the code is big

Comment: I'd say that code wasn't so large that it can't be placed here (and we do insist that code is supplied in the question, not in a link, which is what Fred was saying). Can you copy it in? If you can trim it down to a smaller case, so much the better.

Comment: I posted an answer for you below.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, it's a tad big lol just wondering if OP knows what to do with answers given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this part of your code:

```
  else {
    // set cookie if password was validated
    setcookie("verify", md5($login.'%'.$pass), $timeout, '/');

    // Some programs (like Form1 Bilder) check $_POST array to see if parameters passed
    // So need to clear password protector variables
    unset($_POST['access_login']);
    unset($_POST['access_password']);
    unset($_POST['Submit']);
  }
```

to read as:

```
  else {
    // set cookie if password was validated
    setcookie("verify", md5($login.'%'.$pass), $timeout, '/');

    echo "Username: " . $login;

    // Some programs (like Form1 Bilder) check $_POST array to see if parameters passed
    // So need to clear password protector variables
    unset($_POST['access_login']);
    unset($_POST['access_password']);
    unset($_POST['Submit']);
  }
```

Comment: great work @Fred -ii- now i could see the username .. but it appears only on the firs page then it disappear .. anyway to import to my secured pages ?

Comment: @DZSAT Glad to hear it and that I was able to have been of help, *cheers!*

Comment: but it appears only on the firs page then it disappear .. anyway to import to my secured pages ?

Comment: @DZSAT You'll need to apply the same logic for your other pages. However, you can use sessions for this and assign the username variable to a sessions array.

Comment: sorry dear Fred .. i'm not expert so i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: @DZSAT Have a look at http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7763720/ and http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/sessions.shtml - `session_start();` will be required to be used inside all files using sessions.

Comment: unfortunately bro ! .. i could not make this working

Comment: please tell me how to import the $login to the other php files .. i was trying since yesterday but i didn't know